# Split a string to create SQL filters

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Hello I have a list item which is a string like this :

scope_items = ["4760 5.2 5.1, acs 8.0.0 7.1, chicago 4.1.0 4.0.0 3.2.0 1.0.1 3.0.0"]

That I managed to get "splitted" inside a list I named `scope_list`

```
scope_list = ['4760', '5.2', '5.1,', 'acs', '8.0.0', '7.1,', 'chicago', '4.1.0', '4.0.0', '3.2.0', '1.0.1', '3.0.0']
```

But as you can see the comma (`,`) is stored too...

I want to create a SQL statement like :

```
WHERE (
           columnvalue1 = 4760 
       AND columnvalue2 IN (5.2,5.1)
      ) 
   OR (
           columnvalue1="acs" 
       AND columnvalue2 IN (8.0.0,7.1) 
      )
   OR (
           columnvalue1  = "chicago" 
       AND colmnvalue2 IN (4.1.0, 4.0.0, 3.2.0, 1.0.1, 3.0.0)
      )
```

I'm using SQLAlchemy, I managed the first part (before the OR) like this :

```
or_args = [and_(
table1.c.columnvalue1 == scope[0], 
table1.c.columnvalue12.in_(scope[1:])) for scope in scope_list]
```

How can I do the same thing for all the other values after each `,` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could `split` on the comma:

```
scope_groups = scope_items[0].split(", ")
```

Now each element in `scope_groups` is one group for your rule, where the 0th item is the column and any other items are values:

```
for group in scope_groups:
    group = group.split(" ")
    # use group[0] and group[1:]
```